# Use of Would and Could

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammar

I know that word could. but I don't know properly which situation I need to Use word Would

can you give some examples?

Comment: Well, where are you from? What's your native language? "would" is a conditional or the past subjunctive of "will", the simple past indicative of "will", and other things.

Comment: If you say what language you speak as your first tongue, there may be someone around who might be able to compare "would" with your language and how it translates. I probably can't help you unless you speak French and I only know so much French anymore because it's been almost 9 years since I've really used it.

Comment: my mother tough is tamil

Comment: Okay, well, I'm going to ask for you: If there should be anyone reading this who speaks Tamil, jayanes could use your help in comparing "would" to corresponding constructions in his language.

Comment: Jayanes, I hope my answer might help you out. I've given you the link to the best dictionary on the Internet. It even defines terms in other languages besides English, but I don't know whether it has Tamil in it. You can check. Further, there are 8 definitions below. Read them and try to make them work. They have examples in them.

Comment: You're welcome. Anytime you might need help, just ask. I'm glad I could help you with this question.

Comment: It says this is the word that corresponds to "would" in English: என்று. I've checked online and that's what the translator says. I don't know whether you've already done this. It also may just be one definition of "would"; I don't know as I don't speak Tamil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Would**: This is taken directly from the definition of "would" on freedictionary.com: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/would.

aux.v. Past tense of will

> 1. Used to express desire or intent: She said she would meet us at the corner.
> 2. Used to express a wish. This sense is archaic ("I would you were so honest a man!"—William Shakespeare) except in contexts with an
>      implicit first person singular subject and followed by a clause
>      beginning with that: Would that it stop snowing!
> 3. Used after a statement of desire, request, or advice: I wish you would stay.
> 4. Used to make a polite request: Would you go with me?
> 5. Used in the main clause of a conditional statement to express a possibility or likelihood: If I had enough money, I would buy a car.
>      We would have gone to the beach, had the weather been good. See Usage
>      Note at if.
> 6. Used to express presumption or expectation: That would be Steve at the door.
> 7. Used to indicate uncertainty: He would seem to be getting better.
> 8. Used to express repeated or habitual action in the past: Every morning we would walk in the garden.